# SQL Function Create

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Could you help to rectify an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COST_OF_STAY ( LOS NUMBER)

RETURN NUMBER

AS v_COST :=0

V_PRICE1:=363

v_PRICE2:=218

v_PRICE3:=183

BEGIN

IF LOS :=1 THEN SET COST = LOS*PRICE1;

ELSEIF LOS :>= 2 and LOS :<=5 THEN SET COST = LOS*PRICE2;

ELSEIF LOS:>5 THEN SET COST =LOS*PRICE3;

ELSE NULL

END IF;

RETURN COST

END;
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "assignment" (of a value to a variable) and "condition" (equality of two expressions)? Unfortunately in the very early days of computing, people decided to use the equal sign, =, for assignment, which causes a lot of problems. Anyway: in Oracle (and a few other languages), `:=` is used for assignment. You are using `:` also for comparisons - worse, even for inequalities. Use the colon for assignment **only**, don't throw it all over the place. Popeye explained other errors in addition to this, but I view this one as the main one.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues and it is highlighted in the following code.

Your function can be simplified a lot qhich I did in the following code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COST_OF_STAY ( LOS NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS

-- DATATYPE OF THE VARIABLE MUST BE GIVEN
-- semi colon at the end of each statement was missing
-- v_COST NUMBER :=0;
V_PRICE1 NUMBER:=363;
v_PRICE2 NUMBER:=218;
v_PRICE3 NUMBER:=183;

BEGIN

-- IF clause was not used properly
-- to match the value you need to use = and to assign :=
RETURN CASE WHEN LOS = 1 THEN LOS*V_PRICE1
            WHEN LOS BETWEEN 2 AND 5 THEN LOS*V_PRICE2
            WHEN LOS > 5 THEN LOS*V_PRICE2
       END;  
END;
/
```

Comment: This could be simplified further: `return LOS * case when los = 1 then v_price1 ....` - factor LOS out of the CASE expression.